# playing a dvd using C#

Tags: c#

I have a dvd copied in my hard drive. It has a folder called video_ts. I am planning to run VLC player to play it.
i was wondering how can I play this dvd using c#. I do not want to use a activex control inside c#. All I need to do is run the vlc.exe using process. I have already done that. But how do I select a specific file from the code that will start playig in the vlc player. My code is.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process Proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
Proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe";
 Proc.StartInfo.Arguments = @"C:\Test\Legacy\VIDEO_TS\VIDEO_TS.BUP";
 Proc.Start();
```

I am trying to send the file name as a argument to run it in the vlc.exe . But its not working. Its just opening up the vlc player. I dont want the user to select the file manually.

Comment: What exactly is the context? Would a regular Windows Shortcut do the trick? Everything in your code sample is hard-coded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never done this before myself, so I'm going by what I've just Googled. To start, it looks like you're using the wrong file as your argument. Check out [this page](http://www.gromkov.com/faq/faq2004-0056.html) for a description of video_ts contents and what they all mean.

Beyond that, take a look at http://www.videolan.org/doc/play-howto/en/ch04.html, which describes command-line parameters for VLC. It may be that you have to provide just the path to the video_ts folder instead of to an individual file within it.

Comment: You are actually right. I have to use the video_TS.ifo file instead of video_TS.BUP. It worked after I changed the argument. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

http://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help

From here it seems as if your syntax for the file location needs to be in the form of file://, but I'm not sure.  Also try using a relative path and see if that works.